# Why spring application context loading each time

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring jdbc for DB connection.And each time i run my test java class spring,context is also loading each time. Any suggestion?

My code snippet are below,

appContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context-2.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3i" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Java class:

```
package com.pinovus.dbconnection;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class DbDao {

    private static JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;
    private static ApplicationContext appcontext;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbctemplate() {

        ApplicationContext cx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "appContext.xml");
        jdbctemplate = (JdbcTemplate) cx.getBean("jdbcTemp");
        return jdbctemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbctemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate) {
        this.jdbctemplate = jdbctemplate;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And test java class is :

```
package com.pinovus.dbconnection;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JdbcTemplate jt = new DbDao().getJdbctemplate();
        String qry = "select role from accounts";
        SqlRowSet rs = jt.queryForRowSet(qry);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `getJdbctemplate()` which loads the spring context every time. What do you want it to do?

Comment: now i understand its my code problem,can i do it with out loading application context each time i call getJdbctemplate() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAO shouldn't know about the application context and shouldn't be explicitly looking up things in it. You could rewrite it using [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/jdbc.html) as an example:

```
public class DbDaoImpl implements DbDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }    
    ...
}
```

and you can delete the jdbcTemp entry from the application context xml. Instead make the DAO Spring-managed, creating an entry for it like this:

```
<bean id="dbDao" class="DbDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have to do this with DriverManager

Comment: @jasim: ?? i didn't say not to use the DriverManager. Make your Dao a spring-managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you create new instance each time:

```
new DbDao().getJdbctemplate();
```

and further:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
```

It isn't an issue of Spring. It's up to your design.

And I don't know how to help you as it is just correct Java code: anyway in case of `public static void main(String[] args)` you have to instantiate objects to get deal with them.

Please, provide more info where are your doubts

Comment: ok, now i understand the problem,how to do this with out loading spring context every time i run a program

Comment: Sorry: how much do you know about Java? When run program (`java com.pinovus.dbconnection.test`) each time it not only creates context, but even starts JVM